# Flutter app is crashing when using "carousel_slider 4.1.1" inside listview

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

We have developed a flutter app that uses carousel slider 4.1.1 for image slider viewing. It works with little data but when the data in the list is big it crashes the app and the debug console terminated saying in the last line

> "onServiceDisconnected (crash or killed by oom): pid=0 bindings:WV"

when loading a bunch of images from the network

Below is a piece of code that we have used

```
CarouselSlider(
                              options:
                                CarouselOptions(
                               autoPlay: false,
                               viewportFraction:
                                 1.0,
                               enlargeCenterPage:
                                 false,
                              ),
                              items: (jsonDecode(data[
                                      index]
                                    [
                                    “Images”])
                                  as List<
                                    dynamic>)
                                .cast<String>()
                                .map((item) =>
                                  ClipRRect(
                                   borderRadius:
                                     BorderRadius.all(
                                       Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                   child:
                                     CachedNetworkImage(
                                    imageUrl:
                                      item,
                                    width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                      .size
                                      .width,
                                    fit: BoxFit
                                      .cover,
                                    progressIndicatorBuilder: (context,
                                        url,
                                        downloadProgress) =>
                                      CircularProgressIndicator(value: downloadProgress.progress),
                                    errorWidget: (context,
                                        url,
                                        error) =>
                                      Icon(Icons.error),
                                   ),
                                  ))
                                .toList(),
                             )
```

We have also tried to set the autoplay attribute to true but the app still crashes. Can someone please help how to fix this crash in the flutter app?